# Number rows according to Month/Year by chronological order

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've got a calendar table that contains a column that looks like this

[image]

What I want to do, is create an extra column that assigns each row a number, according to the Month/Year in chronological order.

For Example I want something like this.

```
Month/Year     Count
Jan/2022         1
Jan/2022         1
Feb/2022         2
March/2022       3
March/2022       3
```

I tried to use the index column option, but that just adds one to each column, regardless of the chronological order or if the value is a duplicate to another row or not.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please accept it to mark item as solved

Answer (score 0):

Click select the desired date/month column. Sort if needed

Right click, group by, use operation ALL ROWS

Add column, index column

use arrows atop the grouped column to expand the original columns

[image]